# Is there an built-in UI support in the Ruby unit test framework?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

Is there an built-in UI support in the Ruby unit test framework? Can I show the results of my unit test in the UI?

Answer (score 1):

In ruby 1.8, test/unit apparently had support for a couple of different runners.

```
ruby test/test_my_app.rb --help

Test::Unit automatic runner.
Usage: test/test_my_app.rb [options] [-- untouched arguments]

    -r, --runner=RUNNER              Use the given RUNNER.
                                     (c[onsole], f[ox], g[tk], g[tk]2, t[k])
[snip rest of help]
```

For ruby 1.9, you may need to install the test/unit gem version to get the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

no, I would probably use Cucumber (www.cukes.info) along with capybara (for web browser UI).

Answer (score 0):

No, AFAIK, there is no Ruby unit testing framework that has support for GUI built in.

That's not how it normally works, anyway. Usually, it's the GUIs that support testing frameworks, not the other way round. And in fact, most Ruby GUI IDEs (and some non-GUI IDEs, and GUI non-IDEs as well) support at least `test/unit` and RSpec. Examples include the NetBeans, Eclipse, IDEA and Visual Studio Ruby plugins, Emacs and TextMate.